# Google Cloud SQL and Google App Engine with Java/eclipse: System property rdbms.driver must be set

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, jsp, google-cloud-sql

Im having a bit of an issue using google app engine to access a database created using Google Cloud SQL. I feel the issue is around the JSP file im trying to use, as well as my import options. The error I am getting is as follows:

```
HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /beer.jsp. Reason: 

    System property rdbms.driver must be set.

Caused by:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: System property rdbms.driver must be set.
    at com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.dev.LocalRdbmsServiceLocalDriver.registerDriver(LocalRdbmsServiceLocalDriver.java:80)
    at com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.dev.LocalRdbmsServiceLocalDriver.init(LocalRdbmsServiceLocalDriver.java:73)
    at com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.dev.LocalRdbmsService.init(LocalRdbmsService.java:85)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.startServices(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:581)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.access$700(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:46)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$2.run(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:564)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$2.run(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:562)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.getService(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:561)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.resolveDeadline(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:233)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.doAsyncCall(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:214)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.makeSyncCall(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:147)
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:101)
    at com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.RdbmsApiProxyClient$ApiProxyBlockingInterface.makeSyncCall(RdbmsApiProxyClient.java:89)
    at com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.RdbmsApiProxyClient$ApiProxyBlockingInterface.openConnection(RdbmsApiProxyClient.java:75)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.SqlProtoClient.openConnection(SqlProtoClient.java:58)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:59)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:26)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:243)
    at org.apache.jsp.beer_jsp._jspService(beer_jsp.java:66)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.access$101(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:23)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet$2.run(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:59)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.service(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:57)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Powered by Jetty://
```

I have tried things to try and remedy this, like loading the mysql connector into the boot strap for the project, and this results in a different error. And I feel like this one is closer to the results I want to achieve

```
HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /beer.jsp. Reason: 

    java.sql.SQLException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Caused by:
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:862)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:791)
    at org.apache.jsp.beer_jsp._jspService(beer_jsp.java:114)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.access$101(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:23)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet$2.run(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:59)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.service(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:57)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.Exceptions.newSqlException(Exceptions.java:208)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.SqlProtoClient.check(SqlProtoClient.java:158)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.SqlProtoClient.openConnection(SqlProtoClient.java:60)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:59)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:26)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:243)
    at org.apache.jsp.beer_jsp._jspService(beer_jsp.java:66)
    ... 39 more

Caused by:
java.sql.SQLException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.Exceptions.newSqlException(Exceptions.java:208)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.SqlProtoClient.check(SqlProtoClient.java:158)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.SqlProtoClient.openConnection(SqlProtoClient.java:60)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:59)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:26)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:243)
    at org.apache.jsp.beer_jsp._jspService(beer_jsp.java:66)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.access$101(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:23)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet$2.run(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:59)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.service(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:57)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Powered by Jetty://
```

Also my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

  <!-- Servlets -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>DBConnect</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>beer.client.DBConnect</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DBConnect</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/beer/good</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>beer.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

And Finally my beer.jsp file

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver" %>

<html>
  <body>

<%
Connection c = null;
c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:google:rdbms://asu.edu:cst433team1:team1db/mysql");
ResultSet rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Beers"); %>

<table style="border: 1px solid black">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th width="35%" style="background-color: #CCFFCC; margin: 5px">Name</th>
<th style="background-color: #CCFFCC; margin: 5px">Message</th>
<th style="background-color: #CCFFCC; margin: 5px">ID</th>
</tr> <%
while (rs.next()){
    int beerID = rs.getInt("beerID");
    int breweryID = rs.getInt("breweryID");
    String beerName = rs.getString("beerName");
    String style = rs.getString("Style"); %>



<tr>
    <td><%= beerID %></td>
    <td><%= breweryID %></td>
    <td><%= beerName %></td>
</tr>

<% }
c.close(); %>

</tbody>
</table>
<br />
No more messages!
  </body>
</html>
```

Im really new at using this API plugin for eclipse, so im not sure what other information we may need to figure out whats going on here. But ill provide anything I can if this isn't enough. Also I apologize for the vague amount of information, its kind of all I have to work with my self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is MySQl's issue it dropps out the connection after certain idle time (may be 8 hr by default)

So you need to execute any dummy query that makes the connection live periodically or use thread pools

Comment: isnt beer.jsp making a query? SQL novice here.ResultSet rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Beers");

Comment: but at that time it seems connection has been dropped out

Comment: I made some manual queries from the API Console prior to running my program. Same error :(

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through same issue, luckily the following solution helped me.

Check your Google Cloud SQL settings if they have a correct instance name, your account name and password.

1. Right_click on project -> Google -> App Engine -> check Google Cloud SQL section
   refer [this link explains how to do cloud sql instance settings](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/cloudsql-createapp)
2. Also check that you have access to that instance

Answer (score 0):

If you sure that database have created, you can check eclispe's setting.

project name -> Google -> App Engine Settings -> Google Cloud SQL

Check "enable Google Cloud SQL" and set something.

e.g Instance name and Database name ... etc.